# Referring to tikzpicture center

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

How I can refer to the current or some other `tikzpicture`'s center?
Is there anything like `(current picture.center)` or `(previous picture.center)`?

I'm asking about straight solutions, not requiring to embed `tikzpicture` within node of other `tikzpicture`, like it was shown in [Transforming coordinates, so (0,0) from tikzpicture is put in the desired place of the page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21359/transforming-coordinates-so-0-0-from-tikzpicture-is-put-in-the-desired-place-o/21547#21547).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `(current bounding box.center)` to refer to the current center of the current `tikzpicture`. As soon you add new material which expands the picture the center will move.

Referring to the center of an previous picture is more difficult. You will need to use `remember picture` on it of course and then store the `current bounding box` of it at the end, e.g. by creating a rectangle node with the same dimensions at the center.

Remember that you only can draw from one picture to another if you use the `overlay` picture option which also sets the official picture size to zero. While doing so the `current bounding box` is always zero, so not useful! You would need to draw two normal pictures and connect them then with a third `overlay` picture.

Here some code to achieve this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\tikzset{save bounding box/.style={remember picture,execute at end picture={%
   \path let
         \p1 = (current bounding box.south west),
         \p2 = (current bounding box.north east)
      in node (#1) at (\x1,\y1)
           [rectangle,above right,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,
            minimum width=\x2-\x1,minimum height=\y2-\y1] {};
   % or, if you only want the center:
   %\coordinate (#1) at (current bounding box.center);
}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[save bounding box=first]
   \draw (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
   \draw (0,0) -- (5,5) (0,5) -- (5,0);
   \draw [red] (current bounding box.center) circle (5pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{tikzpicture}[save bounding box=second]
   \draw (0,0) rectangle (8,8);
   \draw (0,0) -- (8,8) (0,8) -- (8,0);
   \draw [red] (current bounding box.center) circle (5pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
%
% Now connect both pictures:
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
   \draw [green,thick] (first.center) -- (second.center);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks. Quick as always. :) Storing center of current `tikzpicture` for future use is perfectly fine to me.

Comment: @przemoc: I added an example now.

Comment: Great addition about `overlay` problem and how to solve it. At first sight I was going to say that your example was not really needed as I got it already earlier, but I would be not fully truthful then, as I wasn't aware of such "corner case". I must also say I really like this attitude of yours: answer first and go into details with edit.