# TikZ picture on the entire frame in beamer without using overlays

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overlays

I have a `beamer` presentation with several TikZ diagrams that spread across the entire frame, i.e., use the full screen size. I am using the overlay option to make sure the picture captures the entire frame:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
  ...
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The problem is that these diagrams are messed up on the notes pages, that can't align them properly.

Is there a way to make a TikZ picture spread across the full page? I tried using a node that is as large as the entire frame, but it was displayed with some margin between it and the top and left edges of the frame.

**Edit**

When not using an overlay or background template, the result is shifted to the right:

```
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=\paperheight, anchor=north west] (a) {};
    \draw [very thick] (a.north west) -- (a.south east);
    \draw [very thick] (a.north east) -- (a.south west);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
```

[image: The X is not on from the corners]

Comment: It would probably help if you could include a minimal example that shows how you include the node. If you say `\node at (current page.north west) [anchor=north west] {...};`, there shouldn't be a gap.

Comment: @Jake I'd have to look in the manual to be sure (gosh, I'm lazy) but I think that to use the `current page` node then you have to use `overlay`.

Comment: @AndrewStacey: From the code snippet, it seems Little Bobby Tables uses `overlay` for his `tikzpicture`.

Comment: Yes, but he wants to get rid of it (at least, that's my understanding of the problem).

Comment: Just looked.  The pgf manual says that both `overlay` and `remember picture` have to be specified to use the `current page` node.

Comment: LBT: By "notes" do you mean the `handout` version?  Are you using any `pgfpages` stuff when generating them?  I find that messes up `remember picture` stuff, but there's a work-around.  The alternative option is to have a frame style with no margins, in which case your question is "How do I define a beamer frame style with no margins and use it only on specific frames".  Either way, a MWE would help considerably ...

Comment: Although the top-voted answer uses `remember picture,overlay` some of the others to this question might be of use: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3915/image-on-full-slide-in-beamer-package

Comment: @AndrewStacey Ok, how I define a beamer frame style with no margins and use if only on specific frames? See edit, it seems like this is the problem.

Comment: Try `\begin{frame}[plain] ...\end{frame}`

Comment: @percusse I did, a plain frame still has margins, apparently.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Sorry to post this many follow up questions but are you using a theme with a `sidebar` ? Eye-balling the shift amount, it really looks like there is an invisible sidebar sitting on the left.

Comment: @percusse I am using the default (plain, I suppose) theme.

Comment: You might want to check [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/334751/93613) to [this related post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/142569/93613), where I compile stuff from different answers to get a **really empty frame** in a non idiosyncratic way, where no residual left margin in a `plain frame` needs hacked over.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you wrap your `tikzpicture` in `\makebox[\textwidth][c]{...}`, the picture will be properly centered and stretch across the whole width.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
 \makebox[\textwidth][c]{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=\paperheight, anchor=north west] (a) {};
    \draw [very thick] (a.north west) -- (a.south east);
    \draw [very thick] (a.north east) -- (a.south west);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That seems to work.  I'll try it around a bit, I'm concerned that the `\makebox` command might be too fragile to handle complex pictures.  If not, that's a solution.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The ends of the "X" don't quite coincide with the corners of the slide.

Answer (score 6):

Here you have two options, second is what Jake suggested and first was taken from
[How to insert a background image in a beamer frame?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7916/1952)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

{
\usebackgroundtemplate{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,very thick,minimum width=\paperwidth-\pgflinewidth,minimum height=\paperheight-\pgflinewidth] [anchor=north west] (mynode) {My node};
\draw (mynode.north west)--(mynode.south east);
\draw (mynode.south west)--(mynode.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{frame}{Frame with background}
\begin{itemize}
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}{Frame with overlay picture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\node[draw,very thick,minimum width=\paperwidth-\pgflinewidth,minimum height=\paperheight-\pgflinewidth] at (current page.north west) [anchor=north west] (mynode) {My node};
\draw (mynode.north west)--(mynode.south east);
\draw (mynode.south west)--(mynode.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{itemize}
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

From beamer user guide *8.2 Frame and Margin Sizes*

> Aside from using these options, you should refrain from changing the “paper size.” However, you can change
>   the size of the left and right margins, which default to 1cm. To change them, you should use the following
>   command:
>   \setbeamersize{⟨options⟩}
>
> The following ⟨options⟩ can be given:
>
> - text margin left=⟨TEX dimension⟩ sets a new left margin. This
>     excludes the left sidebar. Thus, it is the distance between the right
>     edge of the left sidebar and the left edge of the text.

The problem is that this command is only valid in the preamble, so it changes all presentation margins. Here you have a new example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=0pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=\paperheight, anchor=north west] (a) {};
    \draw [very thick] (a.north west) -- (a.south east);
    \draw [very thick] (a.north east) -- (a.south west);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and its result

[image]

Comment: This is what I want, but it works only as an overlay or a background.  In default mode the node is shifted, probably because of the margins.  See my edit.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: I've edited my answer, is it better now?

Comment: It's good to know, but the problem is that it indeed affects the entire presentation.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: I've tested with 'adjustwidth` from `changepage` and it's possible to suppress left margin but a top margin appears.

Comment: The first solution results in an "X" that isn't quite centered. The second solution works fine, though!

Answer (score 2):

Here's my preferred solution: one which uses a method for absolute positioning described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21359/transforming-coordinates-so-0-0-from-tikzpicture-is-put-in-the-desired-place) and [here](http://www.ellipsix.net/blog/2012/12/absolute-positioning-in-tikz-and-beamer.html). It aligns the "X" perfectly.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} %remove navigation symbols
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, shift={(current page.south west)}]
        \draw (0,0) -- (\paperwidth, \paperheight);
        \draw (0,\paperheight) -- (\paperwidth, 0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Or: `\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
        \draw (current page.north west) -- (current page.south east);
        \draw (current page.north east) -- (current page.south west);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}`

Comment: Yes, that is basically Ignasi's second solution.