# Positioning relative to page in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

Consider the following:

Let's say I have a dot. I would like to be able to position this dot anywhere on the page: at the corner, in the middle, anywhere.

So far, despite poring over manuals and experimenting, I can not figure out how to do this. It seems logical that there would be some system that would place a conceptual grid on the page and then allow for an exact placement within that grid.

I'm sure it exists, but I can't seem to find it.

I can make the dot, and all sorts of other shapes, but I just don't seem to have any control over where these shapes appear on the page.

I'm sure this is an obvious question and I have overlooked something.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21359/transforming-coordinates-so-0-0-from-tikzpicture-is-put-in-the-desired-place for how to position in coordinates relative to any point at the page.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Yes, it really does exist and is quite easy to use.

There are quite some subtleties in this as it can be cumbersome to use in several packages. The reason is that the compilation of the document has to be done several times in order to get the correct placement on the screen.

For instance, an A4-paper is not the size of an A3-paper, secondly you can not know the exact page size due to various packages in the making of the document.

One of the packages that is very nice to use this feature in is the [`beamer`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer) package. If you need this method in that package you are required to add `fragile` to the frame (ensures that the compilation will not fail with dubious error messages).

First of all you need to apply the `remember picture` to the `tikzpicture` environment. This enables `tikz` to save the picture size and various segments in the picture. Secondly you need to specify the `overlay` option which puts the picture out of the text-segment, allowing it to be placed on top of text without taking up any space. If you do not specify `overlay` it will be a regular text-box which is placed next to the preceding TeX-box. This is often *not* desirable when positioning relatively on the page. *(Try and remove `overlay` from the example below and see the picture going out of bounds)*

Now, in order to access the page you need the `current page` node which is referring to the rectangular shape that takes up the entire page. Thus you can refer to anchors and whatever you need via this.

Here is an example which gives you an idea...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[paperheight=8cm,paperwidth=12cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \foreach \bound in {north,south,west,east,45} {
      \node[anchor=\bound] at (current page.\bound) {I am \bound-bound...};
  }
  \node at (current page.center) {I am NOT MOOVING!};
  % You can see the border of the page node with this:
  \draw[thick] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the result is:
[image]

## Relative coordinate system

I wished to elaborate on this and also help those who wants the actual *relative* coordinate system of the page. You can also do this by other means, but for easy reference and clear cut code a coordinate system transformation is very easy to understand.

So basically what I have done is creating a `page cs` transformation which transfers the page into a grid as shown in the below code (describing the cs by `(-1,-1) rectangle (1,1)`).

For this you need the `\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem` in order to redefine a cs.
You can check out this in the manual if in doubt of how it is used.

```
% Defining a new coordinate system for the page:
%
% --------------------------
% |(-1,1)    (0,1)    (1,1)|
% |                        |
% |(-1,0)    (0,0)    (1,0)|
% |                        |
% |(-1,-1)   (0,-1)  (1,-1)|
% --------------------------
\makeatletter
\def\parsecomma#1,#2\endparsecomma{\def\page@x{#1}\def\page@y{#2}}
\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{page}{
    \parsecomma#1\endparsecomma
    \pgfpointanchor{current page}{north east}
    % Save the upper right corner
    \pgf@xc=\pgf@x%
    \pgf@yc=\pgf@y%
    % save the lower left corner
    \pgfpointanchor{current page}{south west}
    \pgf@xb=\pgf@x%
    \pgf@yb=\pgf@y%
    % Transform to the correct placement
    \pgfmathparse{(\pgf@xc-\pgf@xb)/2.*\page@x+(\pgf@xc+\pgf@xb)/2.}
    \expandafter\pgf@x\expandafter=\pgfmathresult pt
    \pgfmathparse{(\pgf@yc-\pgf@yb)/2.*\page@y+(\pgf@yc+\pgf@yb)/2.}
    \expandafter\pgf@y\expandafter=\pgfmathresult pt
}
\makeatother
```

This will allow you to do the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,every node/.style={anchor=center}]
  \node at (page cs:0.5,0.3) {0.5,0.3};
  \node at (page cs:-0.25,0.3) {-0.25,0.3};
  \node at (page cs:0,0) {0,0};
  \draw(page cs:-0.25,0) -- (page cs:.75,-0.5);
  \draw[thick] (page cs:-1,-1) rectangle (page cs:1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which results in:
[image]

Comment: How can I not position something relative to `current page.east` but shift it down by some amount?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your query? You can still use the `calc` library for moving below `east`? I.e. `\draw (current page.east) -- ($(current page.east)+(0, -1)$);`?

Comment: Hm, I'm not to familiar with using libraries in tikz, but now I've just added `transform canvas={yshift = -.5cm}` as option for the `\node[…]`, which moves the node down by `.5cm`.

Comment: I would only suggest that if you want the entire canvas moved? Else I think you should look up the `calc` library which is really handy in almost all `tikz` drawings.

Answer (score 19):

Another approach for absolute coordinate positionning: With `(0,0)` in the top left corner of the page and `(1,1)` in the bottom right corner of the page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shift=(current page.north west)]
\begin{scope}[x={(current page.north east)},y={(current page.south west)}]
\draw[red,->,line width=2pt] (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Similarly with `(0,0)` in the bottom left and `(1,1)` in the top right corner of the page. For instance, if you want to position inside the text area, knowing the width of the margins:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shift=(current page.south west)]
  \begin{scope}[x={(current page.south east)},y={(current page.north west)}]
    \draw[red,->,line width=2pt] (0,0) -- (1,1); 
    \draw[blue,->,line width=2pt] ($(0,0)+(1in,1in)$) -- ($(1,1)+(-1in,-1in)$); 
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome. Your idea is interesting, but the origin of the coordinate system thus created is placed at the `top left` and not at the `bottom left` of the page. This does not follow the usual mathematical conventions.

Comment: Hi @AndréC, 
In that case if you want the usual coordinates (0,0) bottom left and (1,1) top right you just need to change a bit the lines above. See code below
```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shift=(current page.south west)]
\begin{scope}[x={(current page.south east)},y={(current page.north west)}]
\draw[thick,red,->,line width=1cm,] (0,0) -- (0.5,0.5) ;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer by adding this code. You can keep the old answer and add this new code as it is customary to do on this site. As I did for example here: [Nested Enumerations overlap](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/531685/138900)

Comment: @AndréC I edited my answer and added both solutions

Comment: This is great and absolutely the most reproducible answer here. Thanks!

Comment: The `shift=(current page.south west)` option for `\begin{tikzpicture}` was marvelous. I was searching for something that like `\node at (current page.center) {X};` would place a rectangle `\draw (-4, -3) rectangle (4, 3);` at the centre of the page.  But `\draw` does not have a positioning argument like `\node at (x, y)`. So this `shift` option worked very nicely on the picture.

Comment: Added a screenshot and showed how to position relative to text margins. Hope this helps.

Comment: @PatrickT Are there "anchors" for the margins? Like `margin.south west` or similar? Then you wouldn't have to put them in manually and if you change them in the `geometry` options, they would always be correct.

Comment: Good question. My usage was just a one-off. You could always define distances in terms of `marginparwidth` and the like, instead of hard-coding the distances...