# Reverse coordinate system/axis in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider the following image:

[image]

When creating a Tikz picture, the X and Y positions origin and continue as the picture A represents it. But what if I wanted it to work like picture B?

I could use the negative values for the Y, but if I wanted it to be positive instead (so if the number increases, the represented point goes down)... Would that be possible?

In other words, can I set the origin to be in the Top-left side of a page?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is very easily accommodated by using the `cs` system of `TikZ`. You can even define your own coordinate systems (say you want a triangular mesh, you can actually do that).

But for linear scaling of the axis you can do:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=-1cm]
  \draw (0,0) -- (1,0) node[below] {$x$};
  \draw (0,0) -- (0,1) node[left] {$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

As opposed to:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}%
  \draw (0,0) -- (1,0) node[below] {$x$};
  \draw (0,0) -- (0,1) node[left] {$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Remark that you can also apply this in scopes:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) -- (1,0) node[below] {$x$};
  \draw (0,0) -- (0,1) node[left] {$y$};
  \begin{scope}[y=-1cm,xshift=2cm] % Notice that we shift the entire `scope`
    \draw (0,0) -- (1,0) node[below] {$x$};
    \draw (0,0) -- (0,1) node[left] {$y$};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The last one will produce:
[image]

## Page reference

For accessing relative placement on the page, please see: [Positioning relative to page in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89588/positioning-relative-to-page-in-tikz/89592#89592)

Answer (score 20):

You can also use `yscale=-1` as an option to either `tikzpicture` or a `scope`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
Inside a \verb|scope|:

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) -- (1,0) node[below] {$x$};
  \draw (0,0) -- (0,1) node[left] {$y$};
  \begin{scope}[yscale=-1,xshift=2cm] % Notice that we shift the entire `scope`
    \draw (0,0) -- (1,0) node[below] {$x$};
    \draw (0,0) -- (0,1) node[left] {$y$};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{2cm}
Inside  \verb|tikzpicture|:

\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=-1]
  \draw (0,0) -- (1,0) node[below] {$x$};
  \draw (0,0) -- (0,1) node[left] {$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

In addition to zertoth’s answer: It’s even posiblie to change the basis vector an not only it’s length with `y={(x,y)}` like

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[y={(-0.5cm,-1cm)}]
  \draw (0,0) -- (1,0) node[below] {$x$};
  \draw (0,0) -- (0,1) node[left] {$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: TikZ with changed basis vector]

Comment: Good point. Maybe i should've elaborated more on that. I have actually previously used a triangular mesh to ease the build-up of a pyramid.