# cs system of tikz fails when using newlength

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

I found this nice answer on reversing `tikz` coordinates

[Reverse coordinate system/axis in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/90000/reverse-coordinate-system-axis-in-tikz?answertab=active#tab-top)

However, it fails one you use `\newlength` as shown in this example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newlength{\lspan}
\setlength{\lspan}{0.5cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=-1cm]
  \draw[green] (0, 0) -- ($(0, 0) + (\lspan, \lspan)$);
  \draw[red] (0, 0) -- ($(0, 0) + (0.5, 0.5)$);

  \draw (0, 0) -- (1, 0) node[below] {$x$};
  \draw (0, 0) -- (0, 1) node[left] {$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Following the logic the red and green lines should coincide.

What is wrong?

Comment: Possibly a bug, but if you do `\def\lspan{0.5}` the result is as expected. Anyway, if you use an explicit unit of measure, it is not multiplied by the scaling factor, I guess by general rule. And you should not mix absolute lengths with relative ones.

Comment: This works as expected. Only when the y-coordinate is unit-less, y-vector (set by `y=-1cm`) is multiplied.