# How to Produce a Replica of This Chapter Decoration with Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, decorations

Can someone either produce, or tell me how (the steps involved) I may produce the following book chapter decoration with Latex (preferably, `pdflatex`)?

[image]

I know there exist external sources that allow one to upload such a picture, whereupon, the LaTeX code is produced---but I do not know how to do that.

Comment: Is this (1) a "draw this image for me question" or (2) is it about inserting a given image before all chapters (without creating it within LaTeX)?

Comment: For (1) you could e.g. use inkscape to create a svg from an image, if that's the goal.

Comment: @dexteritas In answer to your question---I am looking to produce a replica of the image with Latex.

Comment: LaTeX is almost certainly not the right tool for creating a replica of that image from scratch. Why do you not just want to include the image as is? Copyright reasons? Or do you want it vector based rather than raster based?

Comment: @frabjous If the background were perfectly white, then I could use what I posted. However, the image is from a book over 100 years old, and so there is significant discoloring which would not match the white background of the document I am typing. The image should not be in copyright as it comes from a book more than 95 years old. I thought perhaps, something like Mathcha might be able to produce some Tikz code---but it seems that more is involved than one might think.  Finally, I don't think Inkscape generates such code anymore.

Comment: If you only have it as a raster image I'd use a raster editor to remove the background. I got [this result](https://the21stcenturymonads.net/tmp/imgtest.html) just by opening in gimp, selecting the background by color and pressing delete. Took less than minute. You could probably get something even better with a little effort, especially if you have a higher res version to start from. You could run a vector trace in inkscape, but I'm not sure it'll improve the results much.

Comment: @frabjous Many thanks for your very helpful comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not much time to make a detailed answer, but since it is possible I will simplify some steps for you.

1. Watch any video on how to convert any image to vector in Inkscape.
2. Check this answer [How to export svg to tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60666/154390)
3. Watch any video on how to install plugins for inkscape.
4. Already in inkscape with your vectorized image go to extensions>>export>>Export to tikZ path.
5. Use this options [the UI is in spanish sorry]:

[image]

6. This will generate a very long code [This code cannot be placed as MWE since it has more than 3000 characters and the page does not allow copying it.]:

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\begin{document}
\def \globalscale {1.000000}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt, x=0.80pt, yscale=-\globalscale, xscale=\globalscale, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
\begin{scope}[shift={(-54.5242,-89.3565)}]% layer1
  % path847
  \path[fill=black,line width=0.056pt]
    (26.5695,47.2394) 
        .. controls (26.3421,47.0120) and (25.5522,46.5029)
        .. (25.4268,46.5029) .. controls (25.3729,46.5029) and (25.1336,46.6614)
        .. (27.2576,24.6615) .. controls (27.2406,24.6615) and (27.2267,24.6300) 
        .. (27.2267,24.5915) -- cycle(27.0273,24.2495) 
        .. controls (26.9057,24.1725) and (26.9516,23.9265) ... very long code ....
        ... very long code ....
        ... very long code ....
        .. (27.0876,23.9265) .. controls (27.1491,23.9265) and (27.2008,24.0053) 
        .. (27.2138,24.1190) .. controls (27.2368,24.3185) and (27.1889,24.3520) 
        .. (27.0273,24.2495) -- cycle;
  % path847
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

NEXT STEPS...

1. copy the path where you want and scale it in the tikzpicture environment properties.
2. Of course you can skip all these steps since you converted your image to vector since in inkscape you can export it as a PDF and then import it with all the vector properties you want even within the tikz environment.
3. Check this post [Insert an image at the beginning of a chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/172999/154390)
4. Then you can also play with import vector pdf tikz generated images [Scaling different components of tikzpicture together.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/435629/154390)

Comment: Thank you for posting this answer.