# TikZ full page with absolute node positioning

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, fullpage

I am new to tikz and trying to learn how to use it to draw a full page cover page for a report I am writing.  I have successfully changed the margins and can render to the full page, but I am struggling to understand how I can draw rectangles at fixed absolute locations from the bottom on the page.  I want to put tabulars into the rectangle nodes to display name blocks over the water mark image.

So my question is how can I draw the blue and red nodes on my page at absolute locations?  Also can I specify the height ( say 4cm) of the node (rectangle) and center the tabluar vertically in that rectangle?

In my code all I can see in the blue rectangle at the top.

```
        \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
        \usepackage{tikz}
        \usepackage[left=5.2cm,top=2cm,right=1.5cm,bottom=2cm,verbose,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
        \usepackage{etoolbox}

        % Set up full page to draw in 

        \AfterEndEnvironment{myfullpage}{\restoregeometry}
        \newenvironment{myfullpage}{%
            \newgeometry{left=0cm,top=0cm,right=0cm,bottom=0cm,nohead,nofoot}%
        }{%
            \newpage%
        }

        \begin{document}
        \begin{myfullpage}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shift={(current page.south west)}]
                %\node [inner sep=0pt,above right] {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{matrix.eps}};

                % Draw a full page width filled rectangle with tabular over at bottom of page 

                \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay, anchor = west]
                    \node (names) [shape=rectangle,fill=blue,minimum width =\paperwidth] {
                        \begin{tabular}{r l}
                            A & B
                        \end{tabular}
                    };
                \end{tikzpicture}

                % Draw a full page width filled rectangle with tabular over 8 cm from page current page.south west

                \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay, shift={(0 cm, 8cm)}, anchor=west]
                    \node (names) [shape=rectangle,fill=red,minimum width =\paperwidth] {
                    \begin{tabular}{r l}
                            one & two
                    \end{tabular}
                    };
                \end{tikzpicture}

            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{myfullpage}
        \end{document}
```

Comment: It's important to mention that `\usepackage{tikz}` must stay before `\usepackage{geometry}`!

Comment: Here's the system of coordinates that puts (0, 0) in the center and extreme values like (1, 1), (-1, -1) in the corners: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89588/positioning-relative-to-page-in-tikz (second part of the first answer)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this?

[image: full width rectangles]

Note that nesting `tikzpicture`s should be avoided if at all possible as it is known to cause problems.

There is no need to change the `geometry` here: we can just use absolute coordinates relative to the page itself e.g. `(current page.center)` for positioning:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[left=5.2cm,top=2cm,right=1.5cm,bottom=2cm,verbose,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
      \node (back names) [shape=rectangle, fill=blue, minimum height=40mm, minimum width=\paperwidth, anchor=south west] at (current page.south west) {};
      \node at (back names.center) {
        \begin{tabular}{r l}
          A & B
        \end{tabular}
      };
      \node (names) [shape=rectangle, fill=red, minimum width=\paperwidth, anchor=west] at ([yshift=8cm]current page.south west) {
        \begin{tabular}{r l}
          one & two
        \end{tabular}
      };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The tabular is most easily centred by drawing it *after* the blue rectangle with a `center` anchor.

Note that there is not much point in naming two nodes `names`. If you need to refer to the nodes, they need unique names. If not, they don't need names at all.

Answer (score 4):

It can be done with proper choice of anchors (`current page` ) & some shifts:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[left=5.2cm,top=2cm,right=1.5cm,bottom=2cm,verbose,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay, anchor = west]
 \node[fill=blue,anchor=north,minimum height=4cm, minimum width=\paperwidth] (names)
   at ([yshift=4cm]current page.south) {
    \begin{tabular}{r l}
        A & B
    \end{tabular}
    };


 \node[fill=red,anchor=south, minimum width=\paperwidth] (names)
   at ([yshift=8cm]current page.south) {
    \begin{tabular}{r l}
        one & two
    \end{tabular}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]