# Setting the height or position of a block in tikzposter

Tags: tikzposter

I have two poster in tikzposter and would like to hang them next to each other.
Each poster has three blocks.
I would like similiar blocks to have the same position on both posters. How can this be achieved?

Thank you for your time.

EDIT:
code extract:

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait, margin=0mm, innermargin=15mm, blockverticalspace=15mm, colspace=15mm, subcolspace=8mm]{tikzposter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\useblockstyle{Basic}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\block{Title A}{Content A}
\block{Title B}{Content B} 
\block{Title B}{Content C}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

On both posters, the contents of the blocks have different lengths. The problem is to make them the same height (or the same position for that matter).

Comment: please see [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269844/tikz-full-page-with-absolute-node-positioning) and/or [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89588/positioning-relative-to-page-in-tikz)

Comment: @touhami Are those really useful when considering `\block`s defined in the `tikzposter` class?

Comment: @touham I am not really sure, how I can apply the information from those questions to my problem.
I do not have simple nodes but - as Torbjørn T. said - use the \block statement.

Comment: @Spezi sorry I am not sure. can you make your question more clear and add a minimal example of your code?

Comment: @TorbjørnT.  I am not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution.

New command `\mtblock{Title 1}{Poster 1 content}{Title 2}{Poster 2 content}`
that save content and measure height of block

One `.tex` file, to be compiled with  `\firsttrue` for poster 1. and without it or `\firstfalse` for poster 2.

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait, margin=0mm, innermargin=15mm, blockverticalspace=15mm, colspace=15mm, subcolspace=8mm]{tikzposter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\useblockstyle{Basic}

\usepackage{lipsum}% just for the example

\newif\iffirst
\newlength\htblockbox
\newbox\blockbox

\newcommand{\mtblock}[4]{%
\block{\iffirst #1\else #3\fi}{%
\setbox\blockbox\vbox{#2}%
\setlength{\htblockbox}{\ht\blockbox}%
\setbox\blockbox\vbox{#4}%
\ifdim\htblockbox<\ht\blockbox
\setlength{\htblockbox}{\ht\blockbox}%
\fi
\parbox[t][\htblockbox][c]{\linewidth}{\iffirst #2\else #4\fi}}}

\title{Block height}
\author{User}



\begin{document}
\maketitle

%\firsttrue     %uncomment for poster 1: A,B,C
\begin{frame}[t]
\mtblock{Title 1}{Poster 1 content}{Title 2}{Poster 2 content}
\mtblock{Title A}{\lipsum[1]}{Title AA}{\lipsum[1-2]}
\mtblock{Title B}{\lipsum[1]}{Title BB}{\lipsum[1-2]}
\mtblock{Title C}{\lipsum[1-2]}{Title CC}{\lipsum[1]}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I pasted your code into two documents but uncommented the \firsttrue in one of them. I then removed the lipsum command in one of the blocks, to see if it would work. After compiling both documents, the block without the lipsum command was empty. It was however not the same size or position as the corresponding block on the other poster. I am not sure, if I have made a mistake, but the code does not seem to work.

Comment: my idea is to use only one `.tex` file to produce two pdfs one with `\firsttrue` and one without it

Comment: Ah, I see. That works.
However, for some reason the top half of the poster remains empty.

Comment: I will try to see what happen, but this not related to `\mtblock` there is something wrong in your example.

Comment: I tried your code in another editor. Still the same result. Even though I made no modification whatsoever. I just pasted the code.

Comment: @Spezi I mean the problem happen if you replace Content in your first code with some long text like `\lipsum[1]`.

Comment: @Spezi You need to add `\maketitle` command after `\begin{document}`