# How to define fixed height for block in tikzposter

Tags: dimensions, tikzposter

Is there a way to set the height of a (text body) block in `tikzposter`? Based on this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309554/setting-the-height-or-position-of-a-block-in-tikzposter) I tried to do the following:

```
\newcommand{\mtblock}[1]{%
\setbox\blockbox\vbox{#1}%
\parbox[t][\htblockbox][c]{\linewidth}{#1}}
```

with

```
\mtblock{10cm}{tiltle}{body}
```

however, without succes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
\newlength\htblockbox
\newcommand{\mtblock}[3]{%
\block{#2}{%
\setlength{\htblockbox}{#1}%
\parbox[t][\htblockbox][c]{\linewidth}{#3}}}
```

with

```
\mtblock{10cm}{tiltle}{body}
```

Comment: Can you show this in the context of some example code and result to make it easier to understand? 

Generally, it can be nice to control blocks to have the same height if the content just differ slightly, so I think the knowledge would be useful for many.

Comment: It's fairly simple: just place the the first block in your preamble and after `\begin{document}` define the blocks that you want to have the same length by the new `\mtblock` command.