# Get position of a tikzmark

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzmark

In order to solve [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/532948/robustly-add-a-border-to-the-left-of-a-text-spanning-several-pages), I'd like to obtain the absolute `y` position of a `tikzmark` (actually I want the distance from the border of the text area, but I guess it's not too hard to convert between these two values. The goal is to combine it with [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367048/drawing-tikz-line-in-the-margin-for-multiple-pages)). But I can't find how to do, any idea?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,tikzmark}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{changepage}

\begin{document}

\noindent Here is some text.

\begin{adjustwidth}{1cm}{-8em}
  \noindent \tikzmark{hello}Hello. \message{Horizontal distance from border is ???}
\end{adjustwidth}

\end{document}
```

Comment: See also `\pgfgetlastxy`, `\pgfextractx` and `\pgfextracty`.  You will probably also need `\pgfpointanchor` and `\pgfpointdiff`.

Comment: @JohnKormylo in which environment should I put these `\pgf*` commands?

Comment: I usually put them in a tikzpicture, but am not sure if you need to.

Comment: like an empty tikzpicture?

Comment: For \pgfgetlastxy you will need a \path to set the xy location.  But [overlay] will ignore that.

Comment: I was thinking to use `\tikz@scan@one@point\pgf@process(pic cs:...)` otherwise. But it's not really elegant this this is not documented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,tikzmark}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{changepage}
\begin{document}
\noindent Here is some text.
\begin{adjustwidth}{1cm}{-8em}
  \noindent \tikzmark{hello}Hello. \message{Horizontal distance from border is ???}
\end{adjustwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, shift=(current page.north west)]
\draw[red] let \p1=(pic cs:hello) in (\x1,\y1) -| (current page.north) node[right, pos=0.75] {\y1 \xdef\mydim{\y1}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\mydim
\end{document}
```

[image: Page with frames and a distance]

Comment: Thanks. I was not expecting this solution to work when using it on different pages, but it seems to work. However is it possible to store the result of the let in a macro?

Comment: I do not know if there are better ways - also dependent on if it needs to be used outside TikZ: `\draw[red] let \p1=(pic cs:hello) in (\x1,\y1) -| (current page.north) node[right, pos=0.75] {\y1 \xdef\mydim{\y1}};` stores in `\mydim`.

Comment: Oh that's a funny method ^^