# vertical bar along margin to signal changes in manuscript

Tags: changes

I am co-editing a manuscript with someone who is off site.  To help better indicate the changes each of us make and to cut down on emails, I would like to put a vertical bar on the margin next to changes I make, something like this:

```
text not change
\verticalbar{
   text changed
}
text not changed
```

I am aware that the changes made could start/end in the middle of a  line.  In situations like that we want the vertical bar to cover the partial line.  For various reasons \underline or \textcolor would not work for us.

Thanks for your help and suggestions!

Comment: You could use a breakable `tcolorbox`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? e.g. with a simple example?

Comment: You also can use the `leftbar` environment, from the `framed` package.

Comment: There is also the `changebar` package.

Answer (score 1):

After careful consideration, I came to the conclusion that using `tcolorbox` or other box-based approaches is probably not optimal here, since you could only draw a line next to complete paragraphs. From your example I understand however, that the line should also be able to start or end on those lines where the changed part starts or ends, that is, somewhere within the paragraph.

Therefore, I would propose a solution that is based on `tikzmarks`. These marks can be placed exactly where the changes start and where they end, and the red line would then be drawn covering everything between the two lines in which these two marks are placed.

One shortcoming of this solution is, however, that it cannot span over multiple pages.

This example allows you to choose a custom color for the line:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % only used to generate filler text

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\newcounter{changebar}
\newcommand{\changebarcolor}{red}
\newcommand{\changestart}[1][red]{%
    \renewcommand{\changebarcolor}{#1}%
    \stepcounter{changebar}%
    \tikzmarknode{chbar-\thechangebar-start}{\strut}%
}
\newcommand{\changeend}{%
    \tikzmarknode{chbar-\thechangebar-end}{\strut}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[very thick, \changebarcolor] ([xshift={\oddsidemargin+1in-10pt}]current page.west |- chbar-\thechangebar-start.north) -- ([xshift={\oddsidemargin+1in-10pt}]current page.west |- chbar-\thechangebar-end.south);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]\changestart\lipsum[1]\changeend\lipsum[1]

In this sentence, only one \changestart[blue]word\changeend{} was changed.

\end{document}
```

[image]

You will need to compile the document at least twice, in order to get the corrent positioning of the lines.

Note that because of TeX's space-gobbling peculiarity, you need to add one set of empty curly brackets after the macro if a space follows or otherwise tell TeX that the following space should not be ignored.

---

With a bit of work, it is possible to get a solution that works even with page breaks (initially inspired by [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/367237/47927) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/196097/47927) approach):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % only used for filler text

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\getchbarstartendpages}[1]{%
    % #1 = change bar id, 
    \edef\chbarstartmarkid{\csname save@pt@chbar-#1-start\endcsname}%
    \edef\chbarstartpage{\csname save@pg@\chbarstartmarkid\endcsname}%
    \edef\chbarendmarkid{\csname save@pt@chbar-#1-end\endcsname}%
    \edef\chbarendpage{\csname save@pg@\chbarendmarkid\endcsname}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\chbarifsplit}[3]{%
    % #1 = change bar id, 
    % #2 = not split, #3 = split
    \getchbarstartendpages{#1}%
    \ifnum\chbarstartpage=\chbarendpage\relax% 
        {#3}%
    \else%
        {#2}%
    \fi%
}

\newcounter{changebar}
\newcommand{\changebarcolor}{red}
\newcommand{\changestart}[1][red]{%
    \renewcommand{\changebarcolor}{#1}%
    \stepcounter{changebar}%
    \tikzmarknode{chbar-\thechangebar-start}{\strut}%
    \chbarifsplit{\thechangebar}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[very thick, \changebarcolor] ([xshift={\oddsidemargin+1in-10pt}]current page.west |- chbar-\thechangebar-start.north) -- ([xshift={\oddsidemargin+1in-10pt}]current page.west |- current page text area.south);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    }{}%
}
\newcommand{\changeend}{%
    \tikzmarknode{chbar-\thechangebar-end}{\strut}%
    \chbarifsplit{\thechangebar}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[very thick, \changebarcolor] ([xshift={\oddsidemargin+1in-10pt}]current page.west |- current page text area.north) --  ([xshift={\oddsidemargin+1in-10pt}]current page.west |- chbar-\thechangebar-end.south);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    }{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[very thick, \changebarcolor] ([xshift={\oddsidemargin+1in-10pt}]current page.west |- chbar-\thechangebar-start.north) --  ([xshift={\oddsidemargin+1in-10pt}]current page.west |-  chbar-\thechangebar-end.south);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    }%
}

\AddToHook{shipout/background}{
% for older LaTeX installations use instead:
% \usepackage{everypage} 
% \AddEverypageHook{
    \getchbarstartendpages{\thechangebar}%
    \ifnum\chbarstartpage<\thepage\relax% 
        \ifnum\chbarendpage>\thepage\relax% 
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
            \draw[very thick, \changebarcolor] ([xshift={\oddsidemargin+1in-10pt}]current page.west |- current page text area.north) -- ([xshift={\oddsidemargin+1in-10pt}]current page.west |-  current page text area.south);
        \end{tikzpicture}%
        \fi
    \fi
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1] \changestart\lipsum[1]\changeend{} \lipsum[1]

In this sentence, only one \changestart[blue]word\changeend{} was changed.

Hello my friend. What took you so long? How have you been? \changestart[orange]\lipsum[1]\changeend{} \lipsum[1]

\changestart[cyan]\lipsum[1-10]\changeend{} \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Turns out, the `changebar` package does more or less the same ...

Comment: Thanks.  I just tried this and got the "Undefined control" error:   \AddToHook{shipout/background}.  Is that because I am using an old version of TexLive?  (2017/Debian)

Comment: Yeah, it is a newer implementation. You should be able to replace `\AddToHook{shipout/background}{` with `\usepackage{everypage} \AddEverypageHook{`. I am currently working at a better solution anyways.

Comment: @underflow Sorry, I updated the code to make it less complicated. I also added an alternative for your older installation. You just need to comment out the line `\AddToHook{shipout/background}{` and uncomment the other two lines of code.

Comment: I just tried  \usepackage{everypage} \AddEverypageHook{  and got the new error message  \\changestart ...counter {changebar}\tikzmarknode    {chbar-\thechangebar -star...    I will await your new solution.  THANKS!!

Comment: Ok, I just tested with TeX Live 2017 and there seems to be another problem with the `tikzmark` package. But this part is quite essential to the code, because it checks on which page the bar starts and where it ends. The code should work as of TeX Live 2018 though. Sorry =(

Comment: Got it.  Thanks for your help!  One day I will figure out how to update my TexLive on Linux Mint, or wait until the OS got updated :-(

Comment: As proposed by @JasperHabicht , please find the `changebar ` package here: https://ctan.org/pkg/changebar .