# RFC: Node relative coordinate system in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I was dissatisfied with the implicit degree anchors TikZ provides for nodes (i.e., `(node.30)`). I often want to start an path at 30 percent from the left at the lower border of a node. This is of course possible with `calc`, but this feels a little clumsy.

Therefore, I wrote a snippet that defines a node relative coordinate system and hooked it into the parser to provide a convenient syntax. After some usage, I found it so useful that I would like to show it and request some feedback, before sending it to the PGF/TikZ maintainers.

The resulting syntax for 20 percent at the bottom is `(NODE:20,0)`. What do you think?

[image: Example usage of node relative coordinate system]

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}

\makeatletter

% Declare a relative coordinate system, that is relative to the edges
% of a given node.
\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{rel}{%
    \tikzset{cs/.cd,x=0pt,y=0pt,#1}%
    \pgfpointlineattime{(\tikz@cs@x / 100)}%
       {\pgfpointanchor{\tikz@pp@name{\tikz@cs@node}}{south west}}%
       {\pgfpointanchor{\tikz@pp@name{\tikz@cs@node}}{south east}}%
    \edef\tikz@cs@x{\the\pgf@x}%
    \pgfpointlineattime{(\tikz@cs@y / 100)}%
       {\pgfpointanchor{\tikz@pp@name{\tikz@cs@node}}{south west}}%
       {\pgfpointanchor{\tikz@pp@name{\tikz@cs@node}}{north west}}%
    \pgfpoint{\tikz@cs@x}{\pgf@y}%
  }

% Hook into Tikz coordinate parse to provide (<name>:<rel x>x<rel y>)
\def\tikz@parse@relcs#1(#2:#3,#4){%
\tikz@parse@coordinatesystem#1(rel cs:name={#2},x={#3},y={#4})%
}
\let\tikz@parse@relcs@polar@saved=\tikz@parse@polar
\def\tikz@parse@polar#1(#2:#3){%
  \pgfutil@in@{,}{#3}%
  \ifpgfutil@in@%
    \let\@next\tikz@parse@relcs%
  \else%
    \let\@next\tikz@parse@relcs@polar@saved%
  \fi%
  \@next#1(#2:#3)%
}

\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % First we define a border node, that we use as coordinate system
  \node[draw, text width=100mm, align=center, text height=40mm, text depth=40mm](border){};
  % Just some coordinate system
  \foreach \x in {10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90} {
    \draw[black!20] (border:\x,100) -- (border:\x,0) node[black,anchor=north] {\x};
    \draw[black!20] (border:0,\x) -- (border:100,\x) node[black,anchor=west] {\x};
  }


  % Use the explicit coordinate syntax
  \draw (rel cs:x=50,y=0,name=border) -- (rel cs:x=75,y=100,name=border);

  % Use the shorthand version that is hooked into the TiKZ coordinate
  % parser.
  \node at (border:20,30) (A) {A};
  \node at (border:50,75) (B) {B};

  % Some more nice demonstrations
  \node[draw] at (border:25,75) (text) {Long-Text};
  \draw (text:20,0) edge[->,bend right] (A);
  \draw (text:60,0) edge[->,bend right] (B.south);
  \foreach \x in {10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90} {
    \draw (text:\x,100) -- ++(up:5pt);
  }

  % Polar Coordinates still work
  \draw (0,0) -- (30:2cm);

 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! I'm not sure how well this question fits the official desiderata, but it is certainly interesting ;). This is intended for use with rectangular nodes, is it? I have no idea what `RFC` means in this context. To me, it means `Rugby Football Club`, but I'm struggling to make sense of that in this context.

Comment: Currently the implementation relies on the anchors {south,north} {east,west}. So any node that provides these anchors is supported. But yes, I had only rectangular nodes in mind. And RFC means "request for comments"

Comment: This will break polar coordinates if the unit of measurement contains an `x`, as is very common. Try changing `2cm` to `2ex`, for example.

Comment: And note that I can use a macro for the length and/or angle when specifying a polar coordinate e.g. `(30:\myxyz)`. This works OK in simple cases, but I've no idea if it is generally safe with your code.

Comment: I replaced 'x' with ',' as a separator. And as far as I see it, does (node:\myxyz) work also with node relative coordinates.

Comment: I meant more that various kinds of complex expressions can be part of the `(<angle>:<dimension>)` specification for a polar coordinate, including macros and pgfmath expressions. And the code needs to do or say something sensible when misused, of course e.g. if the name does not refer to a node or the syntax is wrong or whatever. Maybe the default error handlers cope with this already - I haven't tested it, but you should if you are thinking of publishing it in any form.

Comment: Try, for example, `\draw (0:{mod(50,6)}) -- ++(1,1);`.

Comment: I AM SORRY..... Should we (re)start from`\tikz@calc@anchor` or `\pgfpointanchor`? Because that is where Ti*k*Z or PGF realizes that `(node.anchor)` is a pair of node and anchor. I expect something like `(node.30,20)`.

Comment: That would make sense, but it would require to integrate the parsing into the \pgfpointanchor subsystem. I will have a look at it

Comment: @Symbol1 There's no need to shout!

Comment: @cfr Oops... I thought it means that i am really sorry... not sarcasm.

Comment: @Symbol1 Why would you be sorry?

Answer (score 5):

This is a long comment.

Recall that Ti*k*Z parses `(something)` as follows:

- Check if it involves calculation `($(U)+(V)$)`
- Check if it is of specific coordinate system `(foo cs: bar)`
- Check if it is an intersection `(intersection-1)` & `(A|-B)`
- Check if it polar or cartesian coordinate `(1:2)` & `(3,4)`
- Check if it is a pre-defined node `(node)`
- Check if it is a node with a predefined anchor `(node.anchor)`
- Check if it is a node with an angle `(node.360)`

So there are two possibilities:

- If a node is very important, `(current page)` for instance, then one can make it a coordinate system: `(current page cs: bar bar bar)`. (see [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89588/positioning-relative-to-page-in-tikz))
- If all nodes are equal, then it should be part of the node-anchor system: The expected syntax are `(node.360)` and `(node.{12,34})`.

Recall that although a node in Ti*k*Z (a shape in PGF) can have many many anchors, it is not always satisfying. Hence PGF introduces **border anchor** so that one can create anchors on the fly. Similarly one could create an **interior anchor** system parallel to border anchors.

By the way, PGF introduces **generic anchor** that creates anchors for all nodes. For example if you want a point "at 30 percent from the left at the lower border of a node", you can write

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclaregenericanchor{30 from left on bottom}{
    \pgf@process{\northeast}
    \pgf@xa=.3\pgf@x
    \pgf@process{\southwest}
    \pgf@x=.7\pgf@x
    \advance\pgf@x by\pgf@xa
}
\makeatother
\tikz{
    \path[nodes=draw]node(A){Apple}(5,0)node(B){Banana};
    \draw[bend right](A.30 from left on bottom)to(B.30 from left on bottom);
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is really helpful. You understand this stuff really well, I think. I just mess around on the surface, but you dive right down. :-)