# How to write information on the bottom left of the page?

Tags: positioning

I wrote two papers in latex, and on the last page, I want to add the following information to the bottom left of the page.

```
university Name
Field of study 
www.rt.de
Eone by: My name
E-Mail-Adresse: myemail
supervisor1:  
supervisor1: . 
supervisor1:
```

Please let me know how to do that.

Comment: Hello, Could you show us the code you write so far and a MWE ? Please

Comment: @flav i just googled how to do it, but the codes i found does not do the what i want or some time deform the page

Comment: From the information you're wanting to include (and the answers you've gotten), it appears you want to include the information on a single page.  If instead you want to include it on every page, you'd want to look into the [fancyhdr](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr?lang=en) package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple way to do it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1-30]%this generates some dummy text

  \vfill
  university Name

  Field of study

  www.rt.de

  Eone by: My name

  E-Mail-Adresse: myemail

  supervisor1:

  supervisor1:

  supervisor1: 

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: It should be `\lipsum[1-30]` (square, not curly).  If you'll look at your first page you'll see 1-30 printed there.

Comment: @alwaysask: You need to add `\parindent=0pt` after `\vfill` to obtain the adequate result.

Answer (score 2):

There's a flexible way of doing this.  Below is a primitive answer: a 
[detailed answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89588/positioning-relative-to-page-in-tikz) is elsewhere on this forum.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}




\begin{document}    
    \lipsum[1-3]%this generates some dummy text 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shift={(current page text area.south west)}]
    \node [above right]{\parbox{\textwidth}{university Name\\
        Field of study\\
        www.rt.de\\
        Eone by: My name\\
        E-Mail-Adresse: myemail\\
        supervisor1:\\
        supervisor1:\\
        supervisor1:}};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Consider to write `\node [above right,inner sep=0pt]` instead of `\node [above right]`.