# Node-local coordinate system

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

This is essentially the same question as [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/459713/assigning-coordinates-in-tikz), [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz) or [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8911/in-a-beamer-slide-highlight-a-region-of-an-image-with-a-rectangle-overlay), but in all three questions the picture that defines the new coordinates is positioned at (0, 0) of the tikzpicture. In my case it is not.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,calc}

\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (TL) at (1+.3*rand,4+.3*rand);
        \coordinate (BR) at (6+.3*rand,1+.3*rand);
        \node [draw,fit=(TL) (BR)]{Background};
        \begin{scope}
            \node at (5,5) {X};
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

As an example, how can I set up a coordinate system (0..10) inside the node so that (5,5) is in the middle of the box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to shift to the south west corner of the coordinate system.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,calc}

\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (TL) at (1+.3*rand,4+.3*rand);
        \coordinate (BR) at (6+.3*rand,1+.3*rand);
        \node [draw,fit=(TL) (BR)] (fit) {Background};
        \begin{scope}[shift={(fit.south west)},
        x={($0.1*($(fit.south east)-(fit.south west)$)$)},
        y={($0.1*($(fit.north west)-(fit.south west)$)$)}]
            \node at (5,5) {X};
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, nested calculation.