# Nested Enumerations overlap

Tags: spacing, formatting, enumerate

I am trying to make a “combined” nested enumeration as shown below in this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsfonts,bm}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ceil{\lceil}{\rceil}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm{\lvert}{\rvert}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\let\DeclareUSUnit\DeclareSIUnit
\let\US\SI
\DeclareUSUnit\mile{mi}
\usepackage{optidef}

\setlength{\labelsep}{1em}

\begin{document}
    \title{\vspace{-2cm} HW}
    \author{John Doe}
    \date{\today}
    \maketitle
    \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin =*]
        \item
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item[(a)-(b)] See MATLAB
            \item[(c)] For this problem, increasing $R$ seems to scale the control effort down at the cost of slowing down the states' response (the system is less oscillatory compared to the original), while increasing the elements of $Q$ seems to increase the control effort, which increases the states' response at the cost of making $\theta\left(t\right)$ more oscillatory than the original combination. In fact, one can verify that the poles of each system are 
            \begin{align*}
                s_1 &= \left\{-0.8098\pm 0.4951j,-2.8409,-3.8327\right\}\\
                s_2 &= \left\{-0.4057\pm 0.3501j,-3.1385,-3.4421\right\}\\
                s_3 &= \left\{-1.0795,-2.1289\pm0.7193j,-5.691\right\}
            \end{align*}
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

However, I am getting this:
[image]

Is there a way to move the inner enumeration such it doesn’t overlap with the outer one?

Comment: Your code is far from minimal, this is also mentioned by others in your previous questions.

Comment: Maybe you are not aware of the fact, that a so-called MWE helps to get help, please have a look at http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228

Answer (score 3):

#### New answer

Like this ?
[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\setlength{\labelsep}{1em}

\begin{document}
    \title{\vspace{-2cm} HW}
    \author{John Doe}
    \date{\today}
    \maketitle
    \begin{enumerate}[align=left]
        \item
        \begin{enumerate}[align=right]
            \item[(a)-(b)] See MATLAB
            \item[(c)] For this problem, increasing $R$ seems to scale the control effort down at the cost of slowing down the states' response (the system is less oscillatory compared to the original), while increasing the elements of $Q$ seems to increase the control effort, which increases the states' response at the cost of making $\theta\left(t\right)$ more oscillatory than the original combination. In fact, one can verify that the poles of each system are 
            \begin{align*}
                s_1 &= \left\{-0.8098\pm 0.4951j,-2.8409,-3.8327\right\}\\
                s_2 &= \left\{-0.4057\pm 0.3501j,-3.1385,-3.4421\right\}\\
                s_3 &= \left\{-1.0795,-2.1289\pm0.7193j,-5.691\right\}
            \end{align*}
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

#### Old answer

[image: screenshot]

I have removed unnecessary packages in this question.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\setlength{\labelsep}{1em}

\begin{document}
    \title{\vspace{-2cm} HW}
    \author{John Doe}
    \date{\today}
    \maketitle
    \begin{enumerate}[align=left,leftmargin =*]
        \item
        \begin{enumerate}[align=left]
            \item[(a)-(b)] See MATLAB
            \item[(c)] For this problem, increasing $R$ seems to scale the control effort down at the cost of slowing down the states' response (the system is less oscillatory compared to the original), while increasing the elements of $Q$ seems to increase the control effort, which increases the states' response at the cost of making $\theta\left(t\right)$ more oscillatory than the original combination. In fact, one can verify that the poles of each system are 
            \begin{align*}
                s_1 &= \left\{-0.8098\pm 0.4951j,-2.8409,-3.8327\right\}\\
                s_2 &= \left\{-0.4057\pm 0.3501j,-3.1385,-3.4421\right\}\\
                s_3 &= \left\{-1.0795,-2.1289\pm0.7193j,-5.691\right\}
            \end{align*}
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: While this does the job of getting rid of the overlap, is there a way to vertically align (c) with (b)?

Comment: Yes with `align=right`, see my update

Comment: +1: I should use the enumitem package more often! :)

Comment: @Superman I would at least upvote a answer if it provides a valid solution for my question.

Comment: @Superman  Logically, (c) should be aligned with (a).

Answer (score 2):

A small variation of the AndréC's answer:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item
    \begin{enumerate}[align=right,leftmargin=4.4em]
        \item[(a) -- (b)] See MATLAB
        \item[(c)] For this problem, increasing $R$ seems to scale the control effort down at the cost of slowing down the states' response (the system is less oscillatory compared to the original), while increasing the elements of $Q$ seems to increase the control effort, which increases the states' response at the cost of making $\theta\left(t\right)$ more oscillatory than the original combination. In fact, one can verify that the poles of each system are
        \begin{align*}
            s_1 & = \{-0.8098\pm 0.4951j,-2.8409,-3.8327\}\\
            s_2 & = \{-0.4057\pm 0.3501j,-3.1385,-3.4421\}\\
            s_3 & = \{-1.0795,-2.1289\pm 0.7193j,-5.691\}
        \end{align*}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, that’s for the hyphen between (a) and (b). What if I put and en dash or em dash in between?

Comment: @Superman, now answer consider en dash between (a) and (b). As you can see, the `leftmargin` is slightly increased (to `4.4em`).

Comment: got it. How does one determine the lengths of the characters like the em dash in order to properly space things like what you did?

Comment: @Superman, with magic power of *Superman* :-). Seriously, `1em` is the width of character M. Width of en dash with space around it is about half of `em`, all parenthesis in labels together are approximately `1em`  lenght, both character in label `1em`, and both `label sep` together has `2em`, so their sum is approximately `4.4em` /well, 4.4 is easier type as 4.5 ;-)/.