# Absolute position of a drawing on the sheet

Tags: positioning, tikz-styles, draw, tikz-pic

I would like to correct a little the position of the drawing (it's a very large drawing, but it's a block in itself).

[image]

The code is really simple (I'm just starting with Tikz):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Sigma demostration draw}
\author{}

%\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\clearpage

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shift={($(current page.west)+(5cm,-5cm)$)}]
 % flecha
 [->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=1cm,font=\scriptsize]
 % estilo circulo
 \tikzstyle{circulo}=[circle,fill=cyan,draw=none,text=black,draw=cyan!40, fill=cyan!10, very thick, minimum size=9mm]
 % estilo cuadrado
 \tikzstyle{cuadrado}=[rectangle,fill=blue,draw=none,text=black,draw=blue!40, fill=blue!10, very thick, minimum size=6mm, minimum width=11mm]

% G1
\node[cuadrado] (g1_1) {$(y_m)$};
\node[circulo] (g1_2) [left = 1cm of g1_1] {$y_m$};
\node[circulo] (g1_3) [right = 1cm of g1_1] {$\neg y_m$};
\node[cuadrado] (g1_4) [above left = 1cm of g1_2] {$y_m$};
\node[cuadrado] (g1_6) [above right = 1cm of g1_3] {$\neg y_m$};
\node[cuadrado] (g1_8) [above right = 0.6cm of g1_2] {$[y_m^k]$};
\node[cuadrado] (g1_9) [above left = 0.6cm of g1_3] {$[\neg y_m^k]$};
\node[cuadrado] (g1_10) [above = 0.6cm of g1_8] {$[y_m^1]$};
\node[cuadrado] (g1_11) [above = 0.6cm of g1_9] {$[\neg y_m^1]$};

% G2
\node[cuadrado] (g2_1) [above = 4cm of g1_1] {$(y_1)$};
\node[circulo] (g2_2) [left = of g2_1] {$y_1$};
\node[circulo] (g2_3) [right = of g2_1] {$\neg y_1$};
\node[cuadrado] (g2_4) [above left = of g2_2] {$y_1$};
\node[cuadrado] (g2_6) [above right = of g2_3] {$\neg y_1$};
\node[cuadrado] (g2_8) [above right = of g2_2] {$[y_1^k]$};
\node[cuadrado] (g2_9) [above left = of g2_3] {$[\neg y_1^k]$};
\node[cuadrado] (g2_10) [above = of g2_8] {$[y_1^1]$};
\node[cuadrado] (g2_11) [above = of g2_9] {$[\neg y_1^1]$};

% G3
\node[cuadrado] (g3_1) [above = 8.5cm of g1_1] {$(x_n)$};
\node[circulo] (g3_2) [left = of g3_1] {$x_n$};
\node[circulo] (g3_3) [right = of g3_1] {$\neg x_n$};
\node[cuadrado] (g3_4) [above left = of g3_2] {$x_n$};
\node[cuadrado] (g3_5) [below left = of g3_2] {$\langle x_n\rangle$};
\node[cuadrado] (g3_6) [above right = of g3_3] {$\neg x_n$};
\node[cuadrado] (g3_7) [below right = of g3_3] {$\langle \neg x_n\rangle$};
\node[cuadrado] (g3_8) [above right = of g3_2] {$[x_m^k]$};
\node[cuadrado] (g3_9) [above left = of g3_3] {$[\neg x_m^k]$};
\node[cuadrado] (g3_10) [above = of g3_8] {$[x_m^1]$};
\node[cuadrado] (g3_11) [above = of g3_9] {$[\neg x_m^1]$};

% G4
\node[cuadrado] (g4_1) [above = 13cm of g1_1] {$(x_1)$};
\node[circulo] (g4_2) [left = of g4_1] {$x_1$};
\node[circulo] (g4_3) [right = of g4_1] {$\neg x_1$};
\node[cuadrado] (g4_4) [above left = of g4_2] {$x_1$};
\node[cuadrado] (g4_5) [below left = of g4_2] {$\langle x_1\rangle$};
\node[cuadrado] (g4_6) [above right = of g4_3] {$\neg x_1$};
\node[cuadrado] (g4_7) [below right = of g4_3] {$\langle\neg x_1\rangle$};
\node[cuadrado] (g4_8) [above right = of g4_2] {$[x_1^k]$};
\node[cuadrado] (g4_9) [above left = of g4_3] {$[\neg x_1^k]$};
\node[cuadrado] (g4_10) [above = of g4_8] {$[x_1^1]$};
\node[cuadrado] (g4_11) [above = of g4_9] {$[\neg x_1^1]$};

% G10
\node[circulo] (g10_1) [below = 1cm of g1_1] {$u_0$};
\node[cuadrado] (g10_2) [below left = of g10_1] {$u_0$};
\node[cuadrado] (g10_3) [below right = of g10_1] {$u_0 \_ u_0^,$};
\node[circulo] (g10_4) [below = 2cm of g10_1] {$u_0^,$};
\node[cuadrado] (g10_5) [below left = of g10_4] {$u_0^,$};


\path   
% G1
    (g1_2) edge [below] node {k} (g1_1)
        edge [left, pos=0.3] node {n} (g1_4)
        edge [left, pos=0.5] node {1} (g1_8)
        edge [bend left, left, pos=0.5] node {1} (g1_10)
    (g1_3) edge [below] node {k} (g1_1)
        edge [right, pos=0.3] node {n} (g1_6)
        edge [right, pos=0.5] node {1} (g1_9)
        edge [bend right, right, pos=0.5] node {1} (g1_11)
% G2
    (g2_2) edge [below] node {k} (g2_1)
        edge [left, pos=0.3] node {n} (g2_4)
        edge [left, pos=0.5] node {1} (g2_8)
        edge [bend left] node {1} (g2_10)
    (g2_3) edge [below] node {k} (g2_1)
        edge [right, pos=0.3] node {n} (g2_6)
        edge [right, pos=0.5] node {1} (g2_9)
        edge [bend right, right, pos=0.5] node {1} (g2_11)
% G3
    (g3_2) edge [below] node {k+1} (g3_1)
        edge [left, pos=0.3] node {n-1} (g3_4)
        edge [left, pos=0.2] node {1} (g3_5)
        edge [left, pos=0.5] node {1} (g3_8)
        edge [bend left, left, pos=0.5] node {1} (g3_10)
    (g3_3) edge [below] node {k+1} (g3_1)
        edge [right, pos=0.3] node {n-1} (g3_6)
        edge [right, pos=0.2] node {1} (g3_7)
        edge [right, pos=0.5] node {1} (g3_9)
        edge [bend right, right, pos=0.5] node {1} (g3_11)
% G4
    (g4_2) edge [below] node {k+1} (g4_1)
        edge [left, pos=0.3] node {n-1} (g4_4)
        edge [left, pos=0.2] node {1} (g4_5)
        edge [left, pos=0.5] node {1} (g4_8)
        edge [bend left, left, pos=0.5] node {1} (g4_10)
    (g4_3) edge [below] node {k+1} (g4_1)
        edge [right, pos=0.3] node {n-1} (g4_6)
        edge [right, pos=0.2] node {1} (g4_7)
        edge [right, pos=0.5] node {1} (g4_9)
        edge [bend right, right, pos=0.5] node {1} (g4_11)
        
% G10
    (g10_1) edge [] node {k+1} (g10_2)
            edge [] node {n} (g10_3)
    (g10_4) edge [] node {n+2} (g10_3)
            edge [] node {k} (g10_5);


\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{10mm}

\end{document}
```

I'd like to see the arrows with the new code like the old pic, but my actual graph is (where there aren't arrows):

[image]

Comment: You can position on the page using the `current page` node [see this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89588/positioning-relative-to-page-in-tikz)

Comment: @Joncarre -- simply add the calc package in the preamble and in the code add the line --  `\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shift={($(current page.west)+(3cm,-2cm)$)}]` -- you can experiment with the coordinates `3cm,-2cm` to your liking -- in place of `current page.west` you can use other predefined anchors corresponding to the compass points such as `west`, `north` and other combinations

Comment: @Joncarre -- do note that your syntax is wrong and will give incorrect positioning -- for `\node[circulo] (g1_2) [left of=g1_1] {$y_m$};` the correct syntax is 
`\node[circulo] (g1_2) [left=of g1_1] {$y_m$};`  -- you can also use `\node[circulo] (g1_2) [left=1cm of g1_1] {$y_m$};`

Comment: @jsbibra first of all, ty for your help. I really appreciate it. My problem now is with arrows and their position... I'm trying to "expand" the arrows but I can't (like the first draw that i posted). Also there're not arrows anymore, just lines. Is there anything wrong with this line? `[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=1.7cm,font=\scriptsize]`

Comment: @jsbibra hey, you there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Sigma demostration draw}
\author{}
\date{February 2021}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\clearpage

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shift={($(current page.west)+(3cm,-2cm)$)}]
 % flecha
 [->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=1.7cm,font=\scriptsize]
 % estilo circulo
 \tikzstyle{circulo}=[circle,fill=cyan,draw=none,text=black,draw=cyan!40, fill=cyan!10, very thick, minimum size=6mm]
 % estilo cuadrado
 \tikzstyle{cuadrado}=[rectangle,fill=blue,draw=none,text=black,draw=blue!40, fill=blue!10, very thick, minimum size=6mm]

% G1
\node[cuadrado] (g1_1) {$y_m$};
\node[circulo] (g1_2) [left of=g1_1] {$y_m$};
\node[circulo] (g1_3) [right of=g1_1] {$\neg y_m$};
\node[cuadrado] (g1_4) [above left of=g1_2] {$y_m$};
\node[cuadrado] (g1_6) [above right of=g1_3] {$\neg y_m$};
\node[cuadrado] (g1_8) [above right of=g1_2] {$y_m^k$};
\node[cuadrado] (g1_9) [above left of=g1_3] {$\neg y_m^k$};
\node[cuadrado] (g1_10) [above of=g1_8] {$y_m^1$};
\node[cuadrado] (g1_11) [above of=g1_9] {$\neg y_m^1$};

% G2
\node[cuadrado] (g2_1) [above = 3.5cm of g1_1] {$y_1$};
\node[circulo] (g2_2) [left of=g2_1] {$y_1$};
\node[circulo] (g2_3) [right of=g2_1] {$\neg y_1$};
\node[cuadrado] (g2_4) [above left of=g2_2] {$y_1$};
\node[cuadrado] (g2_6) [above right of=g2_3] {$\neg y_1$};
\node[cuadrado] (g2_8) [above right of=g2_2] {$y_1^k$};
\node[cuadrado] (g2_9) [above left of=g2_3] {$\neg y_1^k$};
\node[cuadrado] (g2_10) [above of=g2_8] {$y_1^1$};
\node[cuadrado] (g2_11) [above of=g2_9] {$\neg y_1^1$};

% G3
\node[cuadrado] (g3_1) [above = 8.5cm of g1_1] {$x_n$};
\node[circulo] (g3_2) [left of=g3_1] {$x_n$};
\node[circulo] (g3_3) [right of=g3_1] {$\neg x_n$};
\node[cuadrado] (g3_4) [above left of=g3_2] {$x_n$};
\node[cuadrado] (g3_5) [below left of=g3_2] {$x_n$};
\node[cuadrado] (g3_6) [above right of=g3_3] {$\neg x_n$};
\node[cuadrado] (g3_7) [below right of=g3_3] {$\neg x_n$};
\node[cuadrado] (g3_8) [above right of=g3_2] {$x_m^k$};
\node[cuadrado] (g3_9) [above left of=g3_3] {$\neg x_m^k$};
\node[cuadrado] (g3_10) [above of=g3_8] {$x_m^1$};
\node[cuadrado] (g3_11) [above of=g3_9] {$\neg x_m^1$};

% G4
\node[cuadrado] (g4_1) [above = 13cm of g1_1] {$x_1$};
\node[circulo] (g4_2) [left of=g4_1] {$x_1$};
\node[circulo] (g4_3) [right of=g4_1] {$\neg x_1$};
\node[cuadrado] (g4_4) [above left of=g4_2] {$x_1$};
\node[cuadrado] (g4_5) [below left of=g4_2] {$x_1$};
\node[cuadrado] (g4_6) [above right of=g4_3] {$\neg x_1$};
\node[cuadrado] (g4_7) [below right of=g4_3] {$\neg x_1$};
\node[cuadrado] (g4_8) [above right of=g4_2] {$x_1^k$};
\node[cuadrado] (g4_9) [above left of=g4_3] {$\neg x_1^k$};
\node[cuadrado] (g4_10) [above of=g4_8] {$x_1^1$};
\node[cuadrado] (g4_11) [above of=g4_9] {$\neg x_1^1$};

% G10
\node[circulo] (g10_1) [below = 1cm of g1_1] {$u_0$};
\node[cuadrado] (g10_2) [below left of=g10_1] {$u_0$};
\node[cuadrado] (g10_3) [below right of=g10_1] {$u_0 \_ u_0^,$};
\node[circulo] (g10_4) [below of=g10_1] {$u_0^,$};
\node[cuadrado] (g10_5) [below left of=g10_4] {$u_0^,$};
%\node[cuadrado] (g10_6) [below right of=g10_5] {$z$};
%\node[cuadrado] (g10_7) [left of=g10_6] {$z$};
%\node[cuadrado] (g10_8) [above of=g10_6] {$u_0^,$};
%\node[cuadrado] (g10_9) [above right of=g10_6] {$u_0^,$};
%\node[cuadrado] (g10_10) [right of=g10_6] {$u_0^,$};

\path   
% G1
    (g1_2) edge [below] node {k} (g1_1)
        edge [left, pos=0.3] node {n} (g1_4)
        edge [left, pos=0.5] node {1} (g1_8)
        edge [bend left, left, pos=0.5] node {1} (g1_10)
    (g1_3) edge [below] node {k} (g1_1)
        edge [right, pos=0.3] node {n} (g1_6)
        edge [right, pos=0.5] node {1} (g1_9)
        edge [bend right, right, pos=0.5] node {1} (g1_11)
% G2
    (g2_2) edge [below] node {k} (g2_1)
        edge [left, pos=0.3] node {n} (g2_4)
        edge [left, pos=0.5] node {1} (g2_8)
        edge [bend left] node {1} (g2_10)
    (g2_3) edge [below] node {k} (g2_1)
        edge [right, pos=0.3] node {n} (g2_6)
        edge [right, pos=0.5] node {1} (g2_9)
        edge [bend right, right, pos=0.5] node {1} (g2_11)
% G3
    (g3_2) edge [below] node {k+1} (g3_1)
        edge [left, pos=0.3] node {n-1} (g3_4)
        edge [left, pos=0.2] node {1} (g3_5)
        edge [left, pos=0.5] node {1} (g3_8)
        edge [bend left, left, pos=0.5] node {1} (g3_10)
    (g3_3) edge [below] node {k+1} (g3_1)
        edge [right, pos=0.3] node {n-1} (g3_6)
        edge [right, pos=0.2] node {1} (g3_7)
        edge [right, pos=0.5] node {1} (g3_9)
        edge [bend right, right, pos=0.5] node {1} (g3_11)
% G4
    (g4_2) edge [below] node {k+1} (g4_1)
        edge [] node {n-1} (g4_4)
        edge [] node {1} (g4_5)
        edge [] node {1} (g4_8)
        edge [bend left] node {1} (g4_10)
    (g4_3) edge [below] node {k+1} (g4_1)
        edge [] node {n-1} (g4_6)
        edge [] node {1} (g4_7)
        edge [] node {1} (g4_9)
        edge [bend right] node {1} (g4_11)
        
% G10
    (g10_1) edge [] node {k+1} (g10_2)
            edge [] node {n} (g10_3)
    (g10_4) edge [] node {n+2} (g10_3)
            edge [] node {k} (g10_5);
%    (g10_5) edge [] node {r-u} (g10_6)
%    (g10_7) edge [] node {r} (g10_6)
%    (g10_8) edge [] node {r-u} (g10_6)
%    (g10_9) edge [] node {r-u} (g10_6)
%    (g10_10) edge [] node {r-u} (g10_6);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**MAJOR EDIT**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Sigma demostration draw}
\author{}

%\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\clearpage
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, transform shape]
    \node [anchor=north west, inner sep=0pt]
    at (current page.north west)
    {
\begin{tikzpicture}
 % flecha
 [->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=1cm,font=\scriptsize]
 % estilo circulo
 \tikzstyle{circulo}=[circle,fill=cyan,draw=none,text=black,draw=cyan!40, fill=cyan!10, very thick, minimum size=9mm]
 % estilo cuadrado
 \tikzstyle{cuadrado}=[rectangle,fill=blue,draw=none,text=black,draw=blue!40, fill=blue!10, very thick, minimum size=6mm, minimum width=11mm]
% G1
\node[cuadrado] (g1_1) {$(y_m)$};
\node[circulo] (g1_2) [left = 1cm of g1_1] {$y_m$};
\node[circulo] (g1_3) [right = 1cm of g1_1] {$\neg y_m$};
\node[cuadrado] (g1_4) [above left = 1cm of g1_2] {$y_m$};
\node[cuadrado] (g1_6) [above right = 1cm of g1_3] {$\neg y_m$};
\node[cuadrado] (g1_8) [above right = 0.6cm of g1_2] {$[y_m^k]$};
\node[cuadrado] (g1_9) [above left = 0.6cm of g1_3] {$[\neg y_m^k]$};
\node[cuadrado] (g1_10) [above = 0.6cm of g1_8] {$[y_m^1]$};
\node[cuadrado] (g1_11) [above = 0.6cm of g1_9] {$[\neg y_m^1]$};
% G2
\node[cuadrado] (g2_1) [above = 4cm of g1_1] {$(y_1)$};
\node[circulo] (g2_2) [left = of g2_1] {$y_1$};
\node[circulo] (g2_3) [right = of g2_1] {$\neg y_1$};
\node[cuadrado] (g2_4) [above left = of g2_2] {$y_1$};
\node[cuadrado] (g2_6) [above right = of g2_3] {$\neg y_1$};
\node[cuadrado] (g2_8) [above right = of g2_2] {$[y_1^k]$};
\node[cuadrado] (g2_9) [above left = of g2_3] {$[\neg y_1^k]$};
\node[cuadrado] (g2_10) [above = of g2_8] {$[y_1^1]$};
\node[cuadrado] (g2_11) [above = of g2_9] {$[\neg y_1^1]$};
% G3
\node[cuadrado] (g3_1) [above = 8.5cm of g1_1] {$(x_n)$};
\node[circulo] (g3_2) [left = of g3_1] {$x_n$};
\node[circulo] (g3_3) [right = of g3_1] {$\neg x_n$};
\node[cuadrado] (g3_4) [above left = of g3_2] {$x_n$};
\node[cuadrado] (g3_5) [below left = of g3_2] {$\langle x_n\rangle$};
\node[cuadrado] (g3_6) [above right = of g3_3] {$\neg x_n$};
\node[cuadrado] (g3_7) [below right = of g3_3] {$\langle \neg x_n\rangle$};
\node[cuadrado] (g3_8) [above right = of g3_2] {$[x_m^k]$};
\node[cuadrado] (g3_9) [above left = of g3_3] {$[\neg x_m^k]$};
\node[cuadrado] (g3_10) [above = of g3_8] {$[x_m^1]$};
\node[cuadrado] (g3_11) [above = of g3_9] {$[\neg x_m^1]$};
% G4
\node[cuadrado] (g4_1) [above = 13cm of g1_1] {$(x_1)$};
\node[circulo] (g4_2) [left = of g4_1] {$x_1$};
\node[circulo] (g4_3) [right = of g4_1] {$\neg x_1$};
\node[cuadrado] (g4_4) [above left = of g4_2] {$x_1$};
\node[cuadrado] (g4_5) [below left = of g4_2] {$\langle x_1\rangle$};
\node[cuadrado] (g4_6) [above right = of g4_3] {$\neg x_1$};
\node[cuadrado] (g4_7) [below right = of g4_3] {$\langle\neg x_1\rangle$};
\node[cuadrado] (g4_8) [above right = of g4_2] {$[x_1^k]$};
\node[cuadrado] (g4_9) [above left = of g4_3] {$[\neg x_1^k]$};
\node[cuadrado] (g4_10) [above = of g4_8] {$[x_1^1]$};
\node[cuadrado] (g4_11) [above = of g4_9] {$[\neg x_1^1]$};
% G10
\node[circulo] (g10_1) [below = 1cm of g1_1] {$u_0$};
\node[cuadrado] (g10_2) [below left = of g10_1] {$u_0$};
\node[cuadrado] (g10_3) [below right = of g10_1] {$u_0 \_ u_0^,$};
\node[circulo] (g10_4) [below = 2cm of g10_1] {$u_0^,$};
\node[cuadrado] (g10_5) [below left = of g10_4] {$u_0^,$};
\path   
% G1
    (g1_2) edge [below] node {k} (g1_1)
        edge [left, pos=0.3] node {n} (g1_4)
        edge [left, pos=0.5] node {1} (g1_8)
        edge [bend left, left, pos=0.5] node {1} (g1_10)
    (g1_3) edge [below] node {k} (g1_1)
        edge [right, pos=0.3] node {n} (g1_6)
        edge [right, pos=0.5] node {1} (g1_9)
        edge [bend right, right, pos=0.5] node {1} (g1_11)
% G2
    (g2_2) edge [below] node {k} (g2_1)
        edge [left, pos=0.3] node {n} (g2_4)
        edge [left, pos=0.5] node {1} (g2_8)
        edge [bend left] node {1} (g2_10)
    (g2_3) edge [below] node {k} (g2_1)
        edge [right, pos=0.3] node {n} (g2_6)
        edge [right, pos=0.5] node {1} (g2_9)
        edge [bend right, right, pos=0.5] node {1} (g2_11)
% G3
    (g3_2) edge [below] node {k+1} (g3_1)
        edge [left, pos=0.3] node {n-1} (g3_4)
        edge [left, pos=0.2] node {1} (g3_5)
        edge [left, pos=0.5] node {1} (g3_8)
        edge [bend left, left, pos=0.5] node {1} (g3_10)
    (g3_3) edge [below] node {k+1} (g3_1)
        edge [right, pos=0.3] node {n-1} (g3_6)
        edge [right, pos=0.2] node {1} (g3_7)
        edge [right, pos=0.5] node {1} (g3_9)
        edge [bend right, right, pos=0.5] node {1} (g3_11)
% G4
    (g4_2) edge [below] node {k+1} (g4_1)
        edge [left, pos=0.3] node {n-1} (g4_4)
        edge [left, pos=0.2] node {1} (g4_5)
        edge [left, pos=0.5] node {1} (g4_8)
        edge [bend left, left, pos=0.5] node {1} (g4_10)
    (g4_3) edge [below] node {k+1} (g4_1)
        edge [right, pos=0.3] node {n-1} (g4_6)
        edge [right, pos=0.2] node {1} (g4_7)
        edge [right, pos=0.5] node {1} (g4_9)
        edge [bend right, right, pos=0.5] node {1} (g4_11)  
% G10
    (g10_1) edge [] node {k+1} (g10_2)
            edge [] node {n} (g10_3)
    (g10_4) edge [] node {n+2} (g10_3)
            edge [] node {k} (g10_5);
\end{tikzpicture}
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is a good solution for positioning, the problem is that the arrows disappear, as well as the separation between nodes. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: all syntax in your code written as `right/left of=...` needs to be replaced with `left=of...` or `right=of..`

Comment: oh! Ty so much! But.. the arrows are a bit annoying now... I mean, this line doesn't work: `[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=0.5cm,font=\scriptsize]` The distance among nodes doesn't work anymore.

Comment: while using the new syntax use distance  `right=2cm of A`-- similarly `right above=1cm of A`

Comment: Perfect! Ty again. And last question, do you know why I can't see the arrows now? They're edges but not arrows.

Comment: please add the new code you are using as an edit to the old code and the new picture you get as an edit to the old picture -- do not delete the originals --will go through

Comment: Code changed in my first post (also I've uploaded a graph where you can see those edges, but where there're not arrows like before).

Comment: @Joncarre please have a look now at the edit above

Comment: I don't understand why there're two declaration of `\begin{tikzpicture}`, is it necessary?

Comment: please ask a fresh question to attract a larger audience