# Tikzmarks being placed arbitrarily when shifting tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I wanted to center my `tikzpicture` canvas for all my slides so that can consistently position objects. For some reason, when I added `shift=(current page.center)` to all my `tikzpicture` picture environments, the `tikzmark`'s I used positioned their marks extremely arbitrarily. I've tried to distill a MWE below which replicates this strange behaviour.

```
\documentclass[xcolor={svgnames}]{beamer}

\usetheme{boxes}
\useoutertheme{infolines}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

% I tried this, but it didn't work.
%\tikzset{%
%  every picture/.append style={%
%        shift=(current page.center)
%        }}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item \tikzmark{a} abcd
    \item abcd
    \item abcd
  \end{itemize}
  % Including shift in the options causes the tikzmark to move arbitrarily.
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%,shift=(current page.center)]
    \node at (current page.center) {o};
    \node at (pic cs:a) {tikz-a};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Here is what it looks like when I don't shift the `tikzpicture`.
[image: tikzmark doing the right thing]

And now when I do.

[image: tikzmark failing]

I get the same behaviour if I append the shift to `tikzpicture`; I did so with the intention that it would appropriately shift `tikzmark`'s coordinates too.

I also find it funny that the page centers (marked with an 'o') are the same in both cases; this is not usually true with the slides I'm trying to make though.

Finally, I am using the 1.0 version of `tikzmark` from [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikzmark).

Comment: shifting is not centering. You are adding the coordinate of the page center to the picture objects that are given with explicit coordinates, e.g., `(2,3)` would do but `(a.west)` won't) and that's the intended behavior. Nodes do not get affected from these transformations unless `transform shape` is used. That's why the current page node is unaffected. In your slides probably they are not nodes. Long story short there is no extreme arbitrariness

Comment: @percusse: But the question is if the coordinate system of the tikzmark should be affected by such transformations. I would have expected it stay put -- similar to a node beside the tikzmark added with `\tikz[overlay,remember picture]\node (b){B};` which can be used in the tikzpicture and is not affected by the shift.

Comment: @percusse Hmm... I got the `shift` trick from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21359/transforming-coordinates-so-0-0-from-tikzpicture-is-put-in-the-desired-place. My intention is that I'd like the origin to always be at the center of the page. I'm not using any relative coordinates here either, but I presume you are talking about what's going on inside `tikzmark`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer , arunchaganty tikzmark is stationary but the reference to it `(pic cs:a)` is an explicit coordinate (it is a coordinate system) hence obeys the transformation. Probably @AndrewStacey will step in with one of his good-to-read surgeries soon. Otherwise I'll try to make up someting in the evening. If you want to declare objects to reference external objects you can create a local scope and reset the transformations.

Comment: percusse is correct: the apparent shift of the tikzmark is an actual shift of the coordinate returned by the `pic cs` coordinate system.  Perhaps this should be node-like in that it isn't affected by transformations.  I'll take a look to see if that behaviour is easy to switch off.

Comment: When PGF looks up the coordinate of a node then it explicitly inverts the current transformation matrix and applies that to the returned coordinate so that when the transformation is applied (as it is to all coordinates) then the net effect is to do nothing.  This seems like a reasonable thing to do to tikzmark's coordinates.  Shall I consider this a feature request?

Comment: @AndrewStacey: Yes, consider it as a feature request. Imho it is counter-intuitive if marks move around. Why should a mark at the start of page be affected by a shift in a tikzpicture at the end of the page?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer A feature request from you is like a command from anyone else!  As you can see from my answer, it's simple to fix and as you say, it would be the "obvious" behaviour for it *not* to move.  I have a few bug fixes now for tikzmark so I'll upload it to CTAN soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

percusse is correct: the apparent shift of the tikzmark is an actual shift of the coordinate returned by the pic cs coordinate system. Node coordinates get round this by explicitly inverting the matrix and applying it to the coordinate before returning it to the parser.

Here's a modified version of the `pic` coordinate system that is transform-invariant.

```
\documentclass[xcolor={svgnames}]{beamer}

\usetheme{boxes}
\useoutertheme{infolines}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\makeatletter
\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{pic}{%
  \pgfutil@in@,{#1}%
  \ifpgfutil@in@%
    \tmk@labeldef#1\@nil
  \else
    \tmk@labeldef#1,(0pt,0pt)\@nil
  \fi
  \@ifundefined{save@pt@\tmk@label}{%
    \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone\tmk@def
  }{%
      \pgfsys@getposition{\csname save@pt@\tmk@label\endcsname}\save@orig@pic%
      \pgfsys@getposition{\pgfpictureid}\save@this@pic%
      \pgf@process{\pgfpointorigin\save@this@pic}%
      \pgf@xa=\pgf@x
      \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
      \pgf@process{\pgfpointorigin\save@orig@pic}%
      \advance\pgf@x by -\pgf@xa
      \advance\pgf@y by -\pgf@ya
      \pgf@xa=\pgf@x
      \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
      \@ifundefined{save@pg@\csname save@pt@\tmk@label\endcsname}{}{%
        \@ifundefined{save@pg@\pgfpictureid}{}{%
          \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/next page vector}%
          \advance \pgf@xa by \csname save@pg@\csname save@pt@\tmk@label\endcsname\endcsname\pgf@x\relax
\advance \pgf@ya by \csname save@pg@\csname save@pt@\tmk@label\endcsname\endcsname\pgf@y\relax
          \advance \pgf@xa by -\csname save@pg@\pgfpictureid\endcsname\pgf@x\relax
\advance \pgf@ya by -\csname save@pg@\pgfpictureid\endcsname\pgf@y\relax
        }%
      }%
\pgf@x=\pgf@xa
\pgf@y=\pgf@ya
      \pgftransforminvert%
      \pgf@pos@transform{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}%
    }%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

% I tried this, but it didn't work.
\tikzset{%
  every picture/.append style={%
        shift=(current page.center),
scale=.5
        }}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item \tikzmark[\coordinate(mark)]{a}abcd
    \item abcd
    \item abcd
  \end{itemize}
  % Including shift in the options causes the tikzmark to move arbitrarily.
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%,shift=(current page.center)]
\node (p) at (0,0) {O};
\node (q) at (0pt,0pt) {Q};
    \node at (current page.center) {o};
\begin{scope}[xshift=1cm]
    \node at (pic cs:a) {tikz-a};
\end{scope}
\node at (mark) {mark};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{every picture/.style = {}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (p);
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (pic cs:a);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: unmodified tikzmark]

Comment: Just in case the screenshot doesn't make it plain, I'd like to point out that this answer was done completely on an iPad.