# How to use tikz node coordinates in a picture on a different page?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to place a `node` in a `tikzpicture` in relation to the coordinates of a `node` in a previous `tikzpicture`.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[a7paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) {a};
\node[below left=of a] (b) {b};
\end{tikzpicture}

\newpage

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[below=of b] (c) {c};
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{test}

\end{document}
```

I read the answers of a [transforming coordinates](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21359/transforming-coordinates-so-0-0-from-tikzpicture-is-put-in-the-desired-place?rq=1) question and to this [coordinate extraction](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56353/extract-x-y-coordinate-of-an-arbitrary-point-on-curve-in-tikz) question, but I don’t think they work for me here.—Using an overlay also causes problems to the position of the caption.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add `remember picture` and `overlay,remember picture`

```
\documentclass[a7paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\node (a) {a};
\node[below left=of a] (b) {b};
\end{tikzpicture}

\newpage

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node[below=of b] (c) {c};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

you get

[image]

Is that what you are looking for or go at least in the right direction?

From the title of the question I am more thinking you may be looking for something like this:

```
\documentclass[a7paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\node (a) {a};
\node[below left=of a] (b) {b};
\end{tikzpicture}

\newpage

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\path (b|-current page text area.north) coordinate (bshiftedup);
\node[below=0pt of bshiftedup] (c) {c};
\node[anchor=north,align=center,text width=0.9\textwidth] at 
(c.south-|current page text area.center) {\captionof{figure}{test}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

That way the continuation really starts at the top of the page, which might be useful if the picture doesn't fit on a page.

Comment: @Ben This caption is a caption made with `\captionof` and it is wherever you put it. This has nothing to do with `overlay` but only with `node distance` and the like.

Comment: Adding `yshift=4pt` to the last "caption"-node and changing the `text width` to `\textwidth` results in a perfect match for other captionskips/captionwidths